# Build error during Pull Request in the file which was not modified by me

Tags: github, merge, open-source, pull-request

Here is the pull request that I have created: https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Python/pull/10355
It shows error in build/build(pull-request) and when I checked it, there is an error in the file that I did not even modify. I just added a file called binary_addition.py but there is an error as: FAILED web_programming/fetch_anime_and_play.py::web_programming.fetch_anime_and_play.get_anime_episode[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9dHV.png).

I tried to contribute in Open Source project by creating a Pull Request but an error occurred during building of Pull Request in the file that I did not even change.

Comment: the pull request did not succeed because one the automated unit tests failed - you'll have to sort this out and make the test case pass even if it may not be related to your code - no one can judge from here how to proceed